# How to convert XML file into DataSource?

Tags: asp.net, xml, database

first i want to let you know that i never used XML as datasource before.

i have an XML file called "answers.xml" and i need to connect gridview, formview, etc...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Answers>  
<AnswerSet>
    <Answer questionId="MRN">4444</Answer> 
    <Answer questionId="FName">test</Answer> 
    <Answer questionId="LName">patient</Answer> 
    <Answer questionId="AddressPt">blah blah</Answer> 
    <Answer questionId="Governorate">xxxx</Answer> 
    <Answer questionId="InitialCSF">Negative</Answer> 
    <Answer questionId="Diagnosis"></Answer> 
    <Answer questionId="Description"> </Answer>   
</AnswerSet>   
<AnswerSet> 
    <Answer questionId="MRN">1</Answer> 
    <Answer questionId="FName">1</Answer> 
    <Answer questionId="LName">1</Answer> 
    <Answer questionId="AddressPt">1</Answer> 
    <Answer questionId="InitialCSF">Positive</Answer> 
    <Answer questionId="Diagnosis">dx</Answer> 
    <Answer questionId="Description"> </Answer>   
</AnswerSet>
</Answers>
```

I need a way to change the data (edit / delete) in the xml file using .NET

Comment: One suggestion: Use XML like `<MRN>4444</MRN>` not `<Answer questionId="MRN">4444</Answer>`.

Comment: @Dour High Arch: the data entry system depends on a DLL that input the data like that in the xml file. i need to edit/ delete the entered data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use an `XmlDataSource` control, you could also use LINQ to XML to create a datasource object from the file:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("somefile.xml");

var results = from answer in doc.Descendants("Answer")
              select new
              {
                  Question = answer.Attribute("questionId").Value,
                  Answer = answer.Value
              };

GridView1.DataSource = results;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: in your code ".Load("somefile.xml");" how can i load the xml file in the application root?

Comment: Just use Server.MapPath("~/somefile.xml")

Comment: That's a bit more complicated. I'm on my phone right now, but I'll include an example when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2):

The [System.Web.UI.WebControls.XmlDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.xmldatasource%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) class will return an ASP.NET DataSource given an XML file. The given link includes sample code and a walkthrough.

Note that if you must use XML attributes as keys, your XPath expressin will contain things like `Answer[@MRN]`.